# Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "value"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

`Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "value".`

The first time I encounter such an error, what does it mean? please help me

> found in
>
> ---> 
>  at src/components/photo/PhotoForm.vue
>  at src/page/PhotosPage.vue
>
>  at src/App.vue

**template**

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-row class="d-flex"> 
            <v-text-field v-model="title"/>
            <v-file-input v-model="img"/>
            <v-btn @click="addPhoto">AddPhoto</v-btn>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

**script**

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            title: '',
            img: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addPhoto() {
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = () => {
            let photo = {
                id: Date.now(),
                title: this.title,
                url: reader.result
        }
        this.$emit('addPhoto', photo)
    }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.img)    
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<v-file-input v-model="img"/>
```

Should be the original value [] of your image data variable, like this:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            img: []
        }
    },
```